# react similar JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I like the concept of difference comparing and virtual DOM rendering.
But really do not like the way mixing html/js(jfx).
Is there a JavaScript library can do difference comparing and only render the changed DOM components rather than establishing a complex platform?

Your comment welcome

Comment: https://github.com/stevenvachon/handlebars-react ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is hard to say what you call "complex platform", React is a library, not a framework or a platform (maybe RN is), so I would not consider it as a complex. There are pretty much libraries which are using virtual DOM rendering, I have few options for you:

- [Deku](https://github.com/anthonyshort/deku) - a library for rendering interfaces using pure functions and virtual DOM. You write views in a similar way to React (JSX), it looks very similar but more lightweight. You can also make own library based on their diffing and patching API.
- [virtual-dom](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom) - This library originally intended to be as a plain rendering engine, so most likely this is what you actually want.
- [Cycle.js](http://cycle.js.org/) - Functional and reactive framework, it is possible to use JSX (usually no JSX in docs), but not necessary. You can use it with RN as I know.
- [Mithril](http://mithril.js.org/) - One more, really lightweight, I use it a lot before I switched to React.

I would say they are all simple, you don't have o learn specific syntax like while using AngularJS, you use real JavaScript without any hacks.

Hope this help.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution. Here, that question is completely off-topic as it is a tool request, see the [help/on-topic].